# How to populate a treeView from two or more tables in C# console Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, ado.net, treeview

My question is: how to populate a treeView from multiple tables in Visual Studio 2012 and than use treeView_afterSelect_event for DataGridView changes based on my selection in each node in treeView?

I know how to insert one table at a time, but I don't know how am I going to deploy the following query in C# console: I have two tables in my database named as bom$ and part$. Query is running successfully in SQL Server.

```
SELECT bom$.PARENT_NAME, bom$.COMPONENT_NAME
FROM bom$
FULL OUTER JOIN part$
ON bom$.PARENT_NAME=part$.NAME
ORDER BY bom$.PARENT_NAME;
```

Below is the following code from C# console visual studio 2012. Also let me know the after_select_event as well. I've just finished learning diploma of Information Systems Management so I'm new; therefore any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
namespace QBuild_Test2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=COMINSIDE-PC;Initial Catalog=QBuild_Software;User ID=sa;Password=aptech");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                Application.ExitThread();
            }
        }

        private void populate_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //on button click treeview control and datagrid view both will populate at the same time directly from the database
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = @"select PARENT_NAME,COMPONENT_NAME,PART_NUMBER,TITLE,QUANTITY,[TYPE],ITEM,Material FROM bom$ FULL OUTER JOIN part$ ON bom$.PARENT_NAME=part$.NAME ORDER BY bom$.PARENT_NAME;";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView.DataSource = dt;

            treeView.Nodes.Clear();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(@"select * from bom$ order by PARENT_NAME asc");
            cmd2.Connection = conn;

            // I'm able to populate one table in treeview not both tables
            try
            {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt2);
               foreach (DataRow dr in dt2.Rows)
                  {
                   TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["PARENT_NAME"].ToString());
                   node.Nodes.Add(dr["QUANTITY"].ToString());
                   node.Nodes.Add(dr["COMPONENT_NAME"].ToString());
                   treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
                  }
               conn.Close();
             }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
                //this will disable the populate button once the data populated
                populate_btn.Enabled = false;

        }
//this code is to populate result by selecting node based on the selection but failed.
        private void treeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Node.Text != null)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = @"select * from bom$ order by PARENT_NAME ASC;";
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your looking for something like this

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-bind-multiple-sql-server-tables-with-a-treeview-in-a/

Comment: I saw this answer but this link is not that much help; I even tried this way but did not get successful results :(

Comment: if you or any body can show me the exact way how to do it , it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If your saying populate the treeview then after a user selects something use this value to then populate the datagridview? Is that correct

Comment: I'm sorry to getting back to you very late coz I'm havin a lil tough schedule thats why didn't get a chance to login back to this blog. Anywayz, thats correct what you have said but before that I needed to populate the treeview from a two different tables like the way I wrote query up there. So how do you populate treeview from the different columns from two different tables by writing a complex query up there. I request you to please show me the exact way. Thank you

Comment: ok I dont think you understand what we are doing here... the example I gave uses 2 different sources to then combine data to 1 treeview,.... this is what you want to do. Select the records and populate first datatable...then select records and populate the 2nd datatable.... then go through each adding what you want from each table OR combining the data... a simple loop of datatable will do this... the example shows a couple of loops and adding to treeview..main and child adds

Comment: I guess you're right, this is good way doing it, I'll try this, if I still get any sort of error, I'll get back to you in a day. Thanks for your answer...appreciated